# How do I start skype in the system tray?

Tags: skype, window, system-tray

I have skype version 4 is set as one of my startup programs. Whenever skype starts, it pops up in it's full window mode. I would preferably like it to start as just an icon in the system tray.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In Settings - General check the box that is labeled "Start Skype minimized in the system tray." That should get it to open minimized. (It does in gnome 3 at least)

Comment: Not an option anymore.

Comment: The option exists, but for current Skype 8.1 under Ubuntu-MATE 16.04, this option sadly takes no effect…